# $A_{h_k}x(t)=x(t+h_k)$ converges strongly?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

> **Example**: Check if the operator converges strongly:
>   Let $X=L_p(\mathbb{R})\:,\:p\geqslant1$

$A_{h_k}x(t)=x(t+h_k)$ 
If $h_k\to h\:\:k\to\infty$ then $A_{h_k}x\to A_n x$

$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0\\\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t+h_k)-x(t+h)|^p dt<\epsilon^p$ we have strong convergence.

Then the author states:

$||A_{h_k}-A_h||\nrightarrow 0\:\:k\to\infty$ and $h_k\neq h$.

Consider $|h_k-h|=d>0$

$x_0(t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{d}, & \mbox{ if }0<t<d\\
0, & \mbox{ if }t\leqslant0,t\geqslant d
\end{cases}$
$||x_0||_p=1$

$||(A_{h_k}-A_h)x_0||_{L_p(\mathbb{R})}=(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t+h_k)-x(t+h)|^p dt<\epsilon^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}=2^\frac{1}{p}>1$

$||A_{h_k}-A_h||=\sup_{||x||=1}||A_{h_k}x-A_hx||$.

**Question:**

**1)** How does $||(A_{h_k}-A_h)x_0||_{L_p(\mathbb{R})}=(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t+h_k)-x(t+h)|^p dt)^{\frac{1}{p}}=2^\frac{1}{p}>1$? I tried to compute this integral and I do not get this value.

**2)** Is the conclusion of this proof that $A_{h_k}$ does not converge strongly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** I'm fairly certain that we should use

$$x_0(t)=\frac{1}{d^{1/p}}\chi_{(0,d)}(t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{d^{1/p}}, & \mbox{ if }0<t<d\\
0, & \mbox{ if }t\leqslant0,t\geqslant d
\end{cases}$$
instead of what's stated.  Then you get $\|x_0\|_p=1$ and 
$$\|(A_{h_k}-A_h)x_0\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R})}^p=\frac{1}{d}\int|\chi_{(-h_k,d+h_k)}-\chi_{(-h,d+h)}|^p=\frac{1}{d}\int\chi_{(-d,0]}+\chi_{[d,2d)}=2$$

**2)**  No this does not disprove strong convergence.  What it shows is that for each $k$ we can find some $x_0$ such that $\|(A_{h_k}-A_h)x_0\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R})}>1,$ so that 
$$\|A_{h_k}-A_h\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R})}\geq\|(A_{h_k}-A_h)x_0\|_{L_p(\mathbb{R})}>1,$$
and thus $A_{h_k}$ does not converge to $A_h$ in the norm topology of $\mathcal B(L_p(\mathbb{R}))$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Even considering $\frac{1}{d^{\frac{1}{p}}}$ I cannot compute that result. Could you please show me how to do it?

Comment: @PedroGomes I edited to include some of my calculations.  The idea is to write the integrand as a sum of characteristic functions on disjoint intervals.